# How to perform time series analysis on cpu utilization data using python

Tags: python, time-series, xgboost, arima, multivariate-time-series

I am new to time series analysis. I have the following dummy data:

| Timestamp | Cpu_utilization_Percentage | Server_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-11 00:05:00 | 80 | abc |
| 2022-01-11 00:10:00 | 30 | xyz |
| 2022-01-11 00:15:00 | 5 | def |
| 2022-01-11 00:20:00 | 3 | yue |

The dataset is about cpu utilization percentage at each time interval of the day for a given server name.

Table column details:

Timestamp: date with time

Cpu-utilization: values in percentage

Server_name: name of the server

I am able to predict the cpu utilization for given time but how do I predict the time interval for cpu utilization.

Objective is:

How to predict time interval with server name for given cpu uitilization so that i can know at what time interval cpu utilization value is less means its in ideal state.

For example: I want to know what is the time interval where my cpu utilization is less than 5 percent